# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have configured my WebApiConfig like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have one method which accepts one parameter. The accessing URI is `http://localhost:8598/api/WebApi/GetLocationCategory/87`.

This gives me an error: `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI      'http://localhost:8598/api/WebApi/GetLocationCategory/87'`

Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<LocationCategory_CLS> GetLocationCategory(int CatID)
{
    var LocCats = (from lct in entities.tdp_LocationCategories join lc in entities.tdp_LocationMaster on lct.FK_LocationID equals lc.LocationID where lct.IsApproved == 0 && lct.FK_CategoryID == CatID select new { lc.LocationID, lc.LocationName }).ToList();
    List<LocationCategory_CLS> loc = new List<LocationCategory_CLS>();

    foreach (var element in LocCats)
    {
        loc.Add(new LocationCategory_CLS
        {
            LocationID = element.LocationID,
            LocationName = element.LocationName
        });
    }
    return loc;
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem URI Should be : http://localhost:8598/api/WebApi/GetLocationCategory?CatID=87

Answer (score 23):

Try changing your Controller method as

```
public IEnumerable<LocationCategory_CLS> GetLocationCategory(int id) <-- Change
{
    var LocCats = (from lct in entities.tdp_LocationCategories join lc in entities.tdp_LocationMaster on lct.FK_LocationID equals lc.LocationID where lct.IsApproved == 0 && lct.FK_CategoryID == id select new { lc.LocationID, lc.LocationName }).ToList();
    List<LocationCategory_CLS> loc = new List<LocationCategory_CLS>();

    foreach (var element in LocCats)
    {
        loc.Add(new LocationCategory_CLS
        {
            LocationID = element.LocationID,
            LocationName = element.LocationName
        });
    }
    return loc;
}
```

The change is only, changing input parameter from `CatId` to `id`.... It works for me many times..

**Edit** :

---

Its a long time when I look back ***I think*** I know the reason now. `Words Like Jared` is correct, it's all to do with Routing which we specify. If I have a route(default) as :

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
```

And my URL is `/MyController/GetLocationCategory/123`, it will be equivalent to `/MyController/GetLocationCategory?id=123`.

Similarly, if I want to change my parameter name for Id to say CatId, then I need to change the query string parameter(the way I am calling my Controller Action would change). Which would now be :

`/MyController/GetLocationCategory?CatId=123`

Answer (score 7):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Maps to:

`http://localhost:8598/api/Controller/Action/id`

The `WebApi` portion of the url is redundant with `api`. Then modify the method parameter name to match the route:

`public IEnumerable<LocationCategory_CLS> GetLocationCategory(int id)`

This is a good default as it matches the convention.

Alternatively, you can modify the route to use this unconventional parameter name instead:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{CatID}",
            defaults: new { CatID = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Finally, in either case make sure the controller name ends in `Controller`.

Good names: `CustomController`, `CustomApiController`
Bad names: `Custom`, `CustomApi`

Answer (score 3):

what is the name of your controller and action ?

The URL should be

```
http://localhost:8598/api/Controller/Action
```

It does not map to the Route Configuration you have specified, hence the pipeline is unable to locate the correct Controller. The /id should not be in the path it must be in the body or the query parameters ( I got stumped in haste !!)

Example : -

```
public class FooController : ApiController
    {
        public int GetIndex(int id)
        {
            return id;
        }
    }

localhost:58432/api/foo/GetIndex?Id=1

O/P :- 1
```

Note:- If your action name is `GetIndex` then the URL must be `GetIndex` not just Index. Optionally you can specify the `[HttpGet]` attribute for the action.

If you have the following as well in your WebApi.config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then `http://localhost:58432/api/foo?Id=1` would also be a legitimate route. Not sure if you would want that.

Also, With WebAPI as far as possible stick to non action based routing , MVC is meant for that. It is not the recommended way.

Comment: controller name : WebApi , Action name: GetLocationCategory , path is correct i guess ! not able to figure out the problem..

Answer (score 2):

Your request URL is `http://localhost:8598/api/WebApi/GetLocationCategory/87`

Your route is configured to accept: 'api/{controller}/{action}/{id}'

So you need to ensure that the name of your controller is 'WebApiController'.

Also, as stated alredy by @SDG you need to make sure that the name of the parameter to your action method matches what you have in your Route template i.e change 'CatID' to 'id'